# Self join and recursive selection in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, join

Assuming a table as below

```
| ID |  NAME | ROLE | MGRID |
---------------------------
|  1 |   ONE |    5 |   5 |
|  2 |   TWO |    5 |   5 |
|  3 | THREE |    5 |   6 |
|  4 |  FOUR |    5 |   6 |
|  5 |  FIVE |   15 |   7 |
|  6 |   SIX |   25 |   8 |
|  7 | SEVEN |   25 |   7 |
|  8 | EIGHT |    5 |   8 |
```

How do I get a list of all employees reporting to an employee, including the ones who are in subsequent reporting levels below?

I mean, given emp id 5, I should get [1, 2] and given 7, I should get [1, 2, 5, 7]. How do I get this done?

Will self joins be of help here? Need to brush up my knowledge on joins now.

Comment: This can be done using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) but that facility may not be available in your RDBMS. Which database product and version are you using?

Comment: tables are in Oracle and MySQL

Comment: I think you need two things. First get the list of employees reporting to managers and then transpose the rows to columns. I am out of touch with oracle but there was a clause `start with and connect by prior` which gives you a Hierarchical view.

Comment: @megazoe . . . Which version of Oracle?  11g supports recursive CTEs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: and every version since 8.0 supported a much easier syntax using `connect by` (btw: it's 11.2 that supports recursive CTEs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SQL statement using Oracle.

```
select  id, name, role, mgrID
from employees
start with id = 7
connect by NoCycle prior id = mgrid;
```

Please note that the manager for employee 7 is the employee 7 - they are their own manager.  This will cause an error - "Connect By loop in user data'.  By using the NoCycle keyword you can tell Oracle to detect this and avoid the error.

Does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
      FROM emp
START WITH id = 7
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE mgrid = PRIOR id
```

SQLFIDDLE [LINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9399/8)

Comment: In your sql fiddle adding a row with mgr id of 1 or 2 will explain the situation clearly of levels. The query does the job as is.

Comment: Okay; this solves it. Also, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm seems to have the same example! :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you were asking, but if you are willing to choose a finite number of level's to recurse it isn't too bad to write.

```
SELECT table_2.id
FROM table LEFT JOIN 
  (table AS table_1 LEFT JOIN table AS table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.MgrID)
ON table.id = table_1.MgrID
WHERE (((table.id)=7));
```

ETC.