# How to use for loop in mysql, as i Want to search a employee in the Hierarchy of the given manager from input.?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search a employee in the hierarchy of a given manager ID, however I am unable to implement for loop in mysql. I am beginner so need help.
Table is tbl_emp_info.
There are 2 variable empId and managerId.
And need to search if the given emp id does lies any where in the given manager id. 
Also the manager can be manager of other manager and need to search emp id if it lies in any of the hierarchy.
Any help 
?

I have tried SP but I am unsure if SP works in mysql so unable to get any resolution. 
I tried self join and left joint but I don't know to merge all rows together and search if the given emp username exist in the result in mysql.

output shouldbe like either we get empid in return if it exist or ether we get 1 is emp id exist or 0 if the empid doesn't exist anything.

MORE EXPLANATION -

Imagine there is emp id =  123,
There is manager id = 234. 
The manager id can be manager of other managers or like he can be delivery manager or Project manager.
Now I have to search if the empid = 123 is in the hierarchy of the give stake holder.

Like I have to check if the empid exist under his/her hierarchy  or i need to check if the empid is under any of the mangers who is below him etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self join and recursive selection in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084235/self-join-and-recursive-selection-in-a-table)

Comment: What is SP? It might hep to provide the schema of the table as it is hard to understand from your question.